# Looping over subplots and holding

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I'm trying to create a plot and layer multiple functions over each of the subplots. The output I'm getting, however, is only showing the final plot in each iteration. In other words, all subplots are filled with something, but only with the last curve that I 'added' (or at least I thought I did) -- the cyan curve. I tried using `hold on`in a number of different places, to no avail. Does anyone see what the problem might be?

```
%% Training phase

% Setting for plots

figure;

for tai = 1:length(training_algorithms)

    % Create first subplot (and make sure we stay there)
    subplot(3,2,tai);

    % Plot the (sampled) sine function
    plot(x,y,'bx');
    hold on
    colors = ['r', 'm', 'c'];

    for nh = 1:length(num_hid)

        net = networks{tai, nh}; % Load network
        net.trainParam.showWindow = false; % Don't show graph

        % Train network, and time training
        tic;
        [net, tr] = train(net, p, t);
        durations(tai)=toc;

        % Simulate input on trained networks (and convert to double format)
        y_result = cell2mat(sim(net, p));

        % Evaluate result
        [slo, int, correlations{tai}] = postregm(y_result, y);

        % Add network to array
        networks{tai} = net;

        % Plot network approximation results
        plot(x,y_result,colors(nh))

        ylim([-3 3])
        title(training_algorithms{tai});

    end
    hold off
end
```

Comment: `hold off` is rarely necessary; does removing that help?

Comment: Alas, it doesn't.

Comment: That’s mine. Different problem this time though. I reckon it would work fine if I took out the nh-loop and manually plotted the three networks in each facet.

Comment: Like your previous question, does removing the `postregm` call solve this issue? Other than that I cannot spot an issue.

Comment: Yup, there was a sneaky `hold off` at the bottom of that script. Feel stupid now. Thanks @rinkert

Comment: @Inkidu616 no worries. I would recommend to use axes handles in these cases (or better, handle arrays), so you can check the axes handle and see what properties are changed during debugging. Plus you can specify explicitly to what handle you want to plot.

Comment: Aha, thanks! I've still got some work to do, so this may prove useful. I hope I never have to use Matlab again after this though, I'm used to python and boy, is there a difference in flexibility and usability.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this has been answered already but it is also worth noting that even though you are setting the net.trainParam.showWindow property to 'false,' Matlab may still create a new figure and make it active even though it remains hidden. Then any plots you perform after that won't stack like you want unless you make the original plot active again.

For example, if you run the below code (I stripped out all of your specific functions but recreated the affect) you will see that at the end, there are 20 or so figures open but only 1 is visible. Uncommment the line towards the bottom in order to create the kind of stacked subplots you are after... Hope this helps.

Cheers.

```
% Training phase
% Setting for plots
f1=figure(1);

for i = 1:6
    % Create first subplot (and make sure we stay there)
    subplot(3,2,i);
    x=0:.1:2*pi;
    y=sin(x);
    % Plot the (sampled) sine function
    plot(x,y,'b');
    hold on
    colors = {'r', 'm', 'c'};
    for j=1:3
        f2=figure;
        set(f2,'Visible','off');
        y2=sin(x+j);
        % Plot network approximation results
%         figure(f1) % - uncommment me
        plot(x,y2,colors{j})
    end
    hold off
end

figHandles = findobj('Type', 'figure')
```